# lua-cjson decode backslash error

Tags: lua

I have a question about backslash.

`local a = '{"hosts":[".*\\.?example(?:-bar)?.com"]}'
local b = cjson.decode(a)`

The raw string is `[[.*\.?example(?:-bar)?.com]]`.

It will get `Expected value but found invalid escape code at character 14` error. I tried to replace `\\` but it doesn't works.

How can I solve this issue? Thx.

Comment: `a` is not a JSON object -- it's a table.  JSON objects are always strings.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry, this is a mistake. I updated it.

Comment: What about \\\\?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sadly that's not work. I'm not sure this issue is related [this](http://amnon.win/2017/07/10/fix-lua-cjson-to-resolve-backslash/) and [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/362) or not,

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If the string is `'.*\\\\.?example(?:-bar)?.com]'` it works. I'm not sure whether it changes the regex meaning or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lua string literal `'\\'` describes a one-character string, `'\'`.

The JSON string `"\\"` encodes a one-character string, `'\'`.

To write a JSON string by hand, \ is escaped as \.

To write a string as a Lua string literal, each \ becomes \.

So the character \ to JSON is \ and that result to Lua is \\.

> I'm not sure whether it changes the regex meaning or not.

It doesn't change the meaning, because you should find that the *actual string* contains only a single \ after decoding.

However, as a matter of best practice, don't write JSON strings by hand.  Create a table and use the `encode()` function to serialize it as JSON.  This applies in any language.  It is error-prone, for the reasons you see in this example, among others.

Your original implementation was invalid because your string contained a bare \, which isn't valid JSON.  In JSON, \ is always followed by another \ or one of the few things that \ is used to escape, such as \r or \n.